# Show keyboard in certain language Programmatically - Android

Tags: android

In my case i must support 3 different languages. There will be 3 buttons for choosing the language and the keyboard will show up with that language.

Only the keyboard language will be changed, and not the whole app's language.

Any suggestions for that ?